# Swift: combine filter, map to dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, dictionary, filter

I've been having a headache of combining two arrays into one.
The connection of arrays is like levels.Id = rooms.level
Appreciate all the ideas!
So, here are my 2 arrays of dictionaries:

```
let levels = [
  ["Name":"Floor 1", "Order":0, "Id": 1],
  ["Name":"Floor 2", "Order":1, "Id": 2],
  ["Name":"Outdoor", "Order":2, "Id": 3]]
let rooms = [
  ["Name":"Master bedroom", "Order":2, "Id": 3, "Level": 2],
  ["Name":"Guest bedroom", "Order":1, "Id": 4, "Level": 2],
  ["Name":"Kitchen", "Order":0, "Id": 1, "Level": 1],
  ["Name":"Boiler", "Order":0, "Id": 2, "Level": 3]]
```

And result supposed to be like this, sorted by the "Order" value in both arrays :

```
["Floor 1" : ["Kitchen"],
 "Floor 2" : ["Guest bedroom", "Master bedroom"],
 "Outdoor" : ["Boiler"]]
```

This is how i made this array but it looks ugly:

```
func replaceIdWithName(id : Int)->String {
    return rooms.first(where: { $0["Id"] as? Int == id })!["Name"] as! String
}
func getLevelId(id : Int)->String {
    return (levels.first(where: { $0["Id"] as? Int == rooms.first(where: { $0["Id"] as? Int == id })?["Level"] as? Int })?["Name"]) as! String
}
var arr : [String : [Any]] = Dictionary(grouping: rooms.map { $0["Id"] as! Int }, by: { getLevelId(id: $0) })
arr.forEach{ arr[$0.0] = $0.1.map { replaceIdWithName(id: $0 as! Int) } }
```

And before, i've sorted both arrays by this func:

```
func sortLevels(p1:[String:Any], p2: [String:Any])->Bool {
    let i = p1["Order"] as? Int
    let j = p2["Order"] as? Int
    if i != nil && j != nil {
        return i! < j!
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? This site is not intended to be a "please code this homework assignment for me" place.

Comment: I've tried hundreds of options though non of them is working in exactly way i need. I had no intention to make somebody code for me. But as it was my first post here i could miss that i'm obliged to post my silly attempts...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with arrays of dictionaries directly is going to be a type casting nightmare.  But if you want to do it anyways, Swift 4's new Dictionary initializers can help.

Here's an example:

```
let levelNames = [Int:String](uniqueKeysWithValues:levels.map{($0["Id"]! as! Int, $0["Name"] as! String)})
let roomLevels = rooms.map{( levelNames[$0["Level"]! as! Int]! , [$0["Name"]! as! String])}
let levelRooms = [String:[String]](roomLevels, uniquingKeysWith:+)

print(levelRooms)
// ["Floor 1": ["Kitchen"], "Floor 2": ["Master bedroom", "Guest bedroom"], "Outdoor": ["Boiler"]]
```

.

The levelNames variable will act as an index to get a level name from a level Id.

The roomLevels variable is an array of room names with their respective level name obtained using the levelNames variable.  Note that the room name is returned as a single element array to make the next step easier.

levelRooms is the final dictionary initialized with the uniquingKeysWith option which will combine values (room names) for entries with identical keys (level name).   Because the room name was returned as a single element array, we can simply use the + operator for the combining function and it will perform array additions into a multi-element array for the level name.

[EDIT] note that you could hide away most of the type casting while still using the arrays of dictionaries as your data structure by creating functions to access the values by their key names.

```
struct Level
{
   static func Id(_ dict:[String:Any])    -> Int    { return dict["Id"]    as? Int    ?? 0 }
   static func Name(_ dict:[String:Any])  -> String { return dict["Name"]  as? String ?? ""}
   static func Order(_ dict:[String:Any]) -> Int    { return dict["Order"] as? Int    ?? 0 }
}

struct Room
{
   static func Id(_ dict:[String:Any])    -> Int    { return dict["Id"]    as? Int    ?? 0 }
   static func Name(_ dict:[String:Any])  -> String { return dict["Name"]  as? String ?? ""}
   static func Level(_ dict:[String:Any]) -> Int    { return dict["Level"] as? Int    ?? 0 }
   static func Order(_ dict:[String:Any]) -> Int    { return dict["Order"] as? Int    ?? 0 }
}
```

The above solution would then be much more readable and you get the added benefit of not repeating key names in string literals all over your code

```
let levelNames = [Int:String](uniqueKeysWithValues:levels.map{(Level.Id($0), Level.Name($0))})
let roomLevels = rooms.map{( levelNames[Room.Level($0)]! , [Room.Name($0)])}
let levelRooms = [String:[String]](roomLevels, uniquingKeysWith:+)
```

Comment: This is amazing. I couldn't imagine that processing of two plain arrays will need such a lot of code, but what you wrote gave me great start. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Level {
    let name: String
    let order: Int
    let id: Int
}

struct Room {
    let name: String
    let order: Int
    let id: Int
    let level: Int
}
```

first you need to do some mapping for easier work

```
let mappedLevels = levels.flatMap { level -> Level? in
    guard let name = level["Name"] as? String, let id = level["Id"] as? Int, let order = level["Order"] as? Int else { return nil }

    return Level(name: name, order: order, id: id)
}
```

this one levelIdMappings will be used later for easier work

```
let levelIdMappings = mappedLevels.reduce(Dictionary<Int, Level>()) { (result, level) -> Dictionary<Int, Level> in
    var mutableResult = result
    mutableResult[level.id] = level

    return mutableResult
}
```

do also room mapping

```
let mappedRooms = rooms.flatMap { room -> Room? in
    guard let name = room["Name"] as? String, let id = room["Id"] as? Int, let order = room["Order"] as? Int, let level = room["Level"] as? Int else { return nil }

    return Room(name: name, order: order, id: id, level: level)
}
```

now filter only levels which you are interested in and fill levelRoomsMapping ( I could do this with reduce)

```
var levelRoomsMapping = Dictionary<Int, [Room]>()

mappedRooms.filter { levelIdMappings.keys.contains($0.level) }.forEach {
    if var rooms = levelRoomsMapping[$0.level] {
        rooms.append($0)
        levelRoomsMapping[$0.level] = rooms
    } else {
        levelRoomsMapping[$0.level] = [$0]
    }
}
```

and now just filter information what you need, and create final dictionary

```
let finalResult = levelRoomsMapping.reduce(Dictionary<String,[String]>()) { (dictionary, next) -> Dictionary<String,[String]> in
    guard let key = levelIdMappings[next.key]?.name else { return dictionary }

    var mutableDictionary = dictionary
    mutableDictionary[key] = next.value.map {
        $0.name
    }

    return mutableDictionary
}
```

You can paste it to playground and print whatever you like to get better insight

Comment: and of course might be done in shorter way, but I guess it would be less readable

Comment: Huge thanks! I've done it working as i'll show it below but it looks ugly:)

Comment: Not at all, I forgot to sort it(did not spot it). Anyways, if you map your arrays to a struct as I did, you might get a prettier code. Also, it is easier to adapt to change of the key as you will have to change it only in one place. Plus do not use Any if possible, if you can use [String] just use it.